# R function arguments from another environment

Tags: r, function, environment

I was just wondering a simple question:

Say I have the following function, which is basically a SAS MACRO

```
e<-new.env()
e$graph<-function(a,b,c){
  e$plot<-ggplot()+
          geom_text(aes(label=a......))+
          geom_text(aes(label=b......))+
          geom_text(aes(label=c......))
}
e$graph(e$label_1,e$label_2,e$label_3)
```

I am basically using this function as the same way SAS MACRO is functioning, so I can just replace whatever it is in abc, and plot another graph.

However, R is saying that a is missing, since I am calling a in the default environment, but the the function e$graph() is using arguments from environment e.

Do you guys know what should I do?  Maybe just use one argument which is a list, and within each cell, assign the e$label_123 to it?

Comment: Please make your example self-contained and reproducible.

Comment: are you trying to make r function like a sas macro?

Comment: @rawr, yes, and I just figured out I should use list.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using environments, you could use expressions and substitution to replace variables.

Consider this example

```
runmacro<-function(expr, ...) {
    stopifnot(class(expr)=="expression")
    dots<-list(...)
    subexpr<-do.call(substitute, list(expr[[1]], dots))
    eval(subexpr)
}

#define macro
ex<-expression({
    print(paste("Hello",name,"value",x))
})

#run and swap variables
x<-15;
y<-20;
z<-"y";
runmacro(ex, name="David")
runmacro(ex, name="David", x=y)
runmacro(ex, name="David", x="y")
runmacro(ex, name="David", x=as.symbol(z))
```

Here I set up a helper function `runmacro` that takes an expression and will replace any values you name as parameters with the corresponding value. So by passing `name="David"` we replace all occurrences of the variable `name` in the expression with the value of `"David"`. You can replace variables with other variables or other values. Each of the examples demonstrates a different case.

I would define your macro like

```
pe<-expression({
    plot<-ggplot()+
        geom_text(aes(label=a))+
        geom_text(aes(label=b))+
        geom_text(aes(label=c))
})
```

In most cases it's better in R to just write a normal wrapper function, but I will admit that ggplot does some crazy stuff with parameter interpretation so that can be difficult at times.